# What era is this German 10 DM banknote from?

Tags: germany, identification, currency

Exactly what it says on the tin. This is clearly a German 10 mark note of some kind, but I can't find pictures online of any notes like it.

[image: German 10 Deutsche Mark note]

The reverse is completely blank, with some bleed-through from the "DRINGEND" stamp. The white balance on my camera is rather off, and the note is actually far more yellowish than the photo implies.

So, the question is twofold:

1. What era is this note from?
2. What is the meaning of the stamps?

Comment: The resolution is too low, but what is the date of the signature?

Comment: @plasmahh I honestly couldn't tell you - it's 19**, even under a magnifying glass. The resolution is about the same as the printing quality.

Comment: At first glance I thought it was Paul Mccartney on the note.

Comment: Why did you [reject my edit](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/35709)? The current question title has the problem that it doesn’t give any information about the banknote other than that it’s from Germany. Imagine what happens when there is another question about a German banknote (and another one, and another one …). There should be at least one detail in the title that allows to disambiguate/find/remember. The name (as I suggested in my edit) would be one way, a description of the pictured person another way.

Comment: Given the font and serial I would guess it is a 1980 variety, we had some at school

Comment: @unor, your proposed title basically changes it into "What era is this American 10 Dollar bill from?" (except for it being the German counterpart) In other words, all you did was add "10", which isn't very useful for a title.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: No, because Germany has/had currencies other than "Deutsche Mark" (e.g., "Reichsmark", "Alliierte Militärmark", "Euro" etc.). (And even it only *were* the "10", it would still be more useful with than without it. Someone using a search engine to find about their banknote then can easily decide just by looking at the title if this question is relevant or not.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The design is that of the "sailing ship" 10 Deutsche Mark note, a banknote first issued in 1960. The front features [a 16th century painting](https://www.wikiart.org/en/lucas-cranach-the-elder/beardless-young-man) by [Lucas Cranach the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_Cranach_the_Elder). On a real version of the note, the reverse would have depicted a barque of the same type like the German navy sailing ship [*Gorch Fock*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorch_Fock_(1958)), officially meant to represent German openness to the world.

These notes were withdrawn from circulation in 1990.

[image]
<sup>A sample of the real 10 mark note found on Pinterest via Google</sup>

However, in your case the `RECHENGELD` stamp  denotes that it is only [play money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_money), used for educational purposes  according to @Loong in the comments. Which also explains why the reverse is blank.

Comment: _Rechengeld_ is typically used for learning counting and calculating with money (e.g. in school). Play money as in Monopoly would be _Spielgeld._

Comment: @Loong Ah. Both types are called play money in English, didn't know there's a difference in German, thanks.

Comment: The colour, checksum and font sizes used for the serial number also give at least one further hint: that this fake was modeled after pre-1975 series. https://www.bundesbank.de/resource/blob/599692/abdfa7bdfea472f8985c0c2ca06076cd/mL/banknoten-ausgabe-1-data.pdf

Comment: **Rechengeld** were used in schools for math classes. Today schools can order the Euro versions here: [Mein Euro - Spiel- und Rechengeld | Deutsche Bundesbank](https://www.bundesbank.de/de/publikationen/schule-und-bildung/mein-euro-spiel-und-rechengeld-693534)

Answer (score 16):

**This is an addition to Semaphore's answer:**

This is the 10 D-Mark note of the [third edition of the *Deutsche Mark*, the *Gemäldeserie BBk I (1961)* (painting series)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bargeld_der_Deutschen_Mark#Dritte_Serie_Gem%C3%A4ldeserie_BBk_I_(1961)).

It was designed by the Swiss designer and artist [Hermann Eidenbenz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Eidenbenz) who was living in Hamburg, Germany.

It was printed between 1961 and 1990. There are five printing runs which are mentioned under the signature in the lower left corner:

1: 2. Januar 1960  (January 2nd, 1960)
2: 2. Januar 1970  (January 2nd, 1970)
3: 1. Juni 1977    (June 1st, 1977)
4: 2. Januar 1980  (January 2nd, 1980)
5: Change of copyright, no change of date

The red "Rechengeld" stamp means that it is money for children to learn using cash. The blue stamp "Dringend" only means "Urgent", I do not know what purpose it has.

**To all anglophones:** It is *Deutsche Mark*, *D-Mark* or even shorter simply *Mark*, not <strike>Deutschemark</strike> or <strike>Deutschmark</strike> or — simply stop it, ok?
[Yeah, I know how it is called in English, but it was always grating to German ears.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Mark)

Comment: +1 for teaching me that "Deutschmark" is incorrect and potentially annoying to German ears.

Comment: We won the war, we get to call it whatever we like in occupied territory. :p (just kidding, the point that it's two words was worth making).

Comment: As a math guy I want to ask: Was the next Zehnmarkschein after this the one showing Gauss? (I don't know how to produce an eszet with my keyboard, sorry.)

Comment: Never mind. The page you linked to explains that the note with Gauss' portrait on a tenner was in use from 1991 on (until the Euro took over I guess).

Comment: Getting upset about _what_ (not _how_) someone else calls your currency seems a bit strange... or are you telling German speakers that the Brits use the _pound_, and not a ["Pfund"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfund_Sterling)?

Comment: @oerkelens :o) It chases me since school...we have Italian Lira, Turkish Lira, Dutch guilder, French franc, Swiss franc, Spanish peseta and...*Deutschmark*. Not German mark, **Deutschmark**. **WHY??** Not only are the German words (!) used as base (in contrast to pound/Pfund), they are *glued* together with a character amputated. And when different anglophones speak it out....it's like listening to a schoolboy playing violin as rookie. Perhaps I am an exception, but I suffer. :o)

Comment: @ThorstenS. Well, I guess you should be happy with the Euro, then - although that's also pronounced in widely different ways :P

Comment: "Not German mark, Deutschmark. WHY??" Because Germans **love** to glue words together and make absurdities like Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän instead of Donau 
Dampfer Unternehmen Kapitän.

Comment: @ThorstenS The German words were used because **DM** was used as the abbreviation of **Deutsche Mark** that was printed on the Banknotes and on the coins. Lira (in English: Pound which came from the latin libra, just as the **d** came from the roman coin **denarius**) was used in Italy, but also in Turkey where they add 'Turkish'  to the name (TL). So it is not uncommon in English to use the original name of the currency, especially when that is what is written on the note or coin.

Answer (score 0):

It is evidently a play money banknote that is modeled after the BBk I series in print from 1960–1970 (while the whole design was indeed issued until 1990).

Reasons:

1. The serial number seems not only to be coloured wrongly, but also has characters all of the same height. This was changed mid-series in 1975: the red numbers would then start with characters which were 0.6 mm larger then the rest.
   <sub>(—Source: Deutsche Bundesbank: "Kursfähige Banknoten", January 1986. [PDF](https://www.bundesbank.de/resource/blob/599692/abdfa7bdfea472f8985c0c2ca06076cd/mL/banknoten-ausgabe-1-data.pdf))</sub>
2. The signatures on display in the question are those of [Karl Blessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Blessing) and [Heinrich Troeger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Troeger) (the last using his preferred first name "Doctor", then president and vice-president of the [Bundesbank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Bundesbank#Presidents_of_the_Bundesbank):

   > [image]

Real banknotes of this kind would have circulated only from 1963 onwards.

Note that I write the bill is *modeled* after that series. As most wouldn't notice the subtle differences anyway, *this* actual play-bill in question might also have been printed later.

> [image]
>   <sup>— Bundesbank 1986, showing the latest signatures, click for large</sup>

Which narrows this down to the model used after comparison of possible signatures

## 02.01.1960 (Blessing / Dr. Troeger):

[image]

## 02.01.1970 (Klasen / Emminger):

[image]

## 01.06.1977 (Emminger / Pöhl):

[image]

## 02.01.1980 (Pöhl / Schlesinger):

[image]

A later model of this exact Rechengeld shows the signatures of Klasen/Emminger and a date of 1970, making this based on the model from between 1975–1977:
[image]
<sub>— Src: [Spielgeld DM](http://www.testnotes.info/html/spielgeld_dm.html); although that one has the proper reverse printed as well.</sub>

Should anyone be into collecting this stuff:
— Günter Aschoff: ["Deutsches Kinderspielgeld: ein numismatisches Randgebiet"](https://books.google.com/books?id=avgGhPANrLkC), Ed. M&S, 2009.